# Using a macro to add a new row onto a table pulling values from other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a macro to work which adds a new row into a table, inserting values from another worksheet.

So far I have either managed to get the macro to insert the first row, however subsequent rows then overwrite the previous. Currently, I have put the 'Line' variable in which produces some different behaviour where the first row inserts 3 times, then subsequent rows are inserted a few rows further down.

Extract below:

```
Sub UpdateItemIndex(ItemName As String)

    Dim ItemIndexSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ItemIndexTable As ListObject
    Dim NewEntryRow As ListRow
    Dim NewEntryRowIndex As Integer
    Dim RangeName As String
    
    Set ItemIndexSheet = Sheets("Item Index")
    ItemIndexSheet.Select
    
    
    Set ItemIndexTable = ItemIndexSheet.ListObjects(1)
    'Remove any filters
    ItemIndexTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    Set NewEntryRow = ItemIndexTable.ListRows.Add
    
    NewEntryRowIndex = NewEntryRow.Index
    
    'Line = Range("NextItemIndex").Value
    Line = Worksheets("Resources").Cells(2, 5)
    
    NewEntryRow.Range(Line, "A").Value = ItemName
       
    RangeName = ItemName & "!" & "ItemTitle"
    NewEntryRow.Range(Line, "B").Formula = "=" & ItemName & "!" & Range(RangeName).Address
    
    RangeName = ItemName & "!" & "ItemStatus"
    NewEntryRow.Range(Line, "C").Formula = "=" & ItemName & "!" & Range(RangeName).Address
       
End Sub
```

Prior to the 'Line' variable, the new row entry commands were:

```
NewEntryRow.Range(1, "B").Formula = "=" & ItemName & "!" & Range(RangeName).Address
```

This is part of a larger macro where a click button generates a new worksheet and a table updates with the new values.

I'm new to VBA so would be grateful for any indication as to what the problem is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have `NewEntryRow` - which represents the new row - you definitly don't need the index of it. `NewEntryRow` has only one row!

This should work:

```vb
With NewEntryRow
    .Range(1, "A") = ItemName
    .Range(1, "B") = "=" & ItemName & "!ItemTitle"
    .Range(1, "C") = "=" & ItemName & "!ItemStatus"
End With
```

As you "named" the Title and Status cells you can refer to them by name. You don't need the address.

--- update ---
You need to add following lines to turn automatic formula updating off:

```vb
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    With NewEntryRow
        .Range(1, "A") = ItemName 
        .Range(1, "B") = "=" & ItemName & "!ItemTitle"
        .Range(1, "C") = "=" & ItemName & "!ItemStatus"
    End With
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True
```

This will result in a lot of red signs - as Excel expects a formula to be consistend within the table

If you can live with an `INDIRECT` formula you would avoid this:

```vb
    With NewEntryRow
        .Range(1, "A") = ItemName 
        .Range(1, "B") = "=INDIRECT([@" & ItemIndexTable.ListColumns(1).Name & "] & ""!ItemTitle"")"
        .Range(1, "C") = "=INDIRECT([@" & ItemIndexTable.ListColumns(1).Name & "] & ""!ItemStatus"")"
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you, thats a lot more elegant! I have tried it and it inserts a new row each time, the only problem I am now experiencing is the previous rows being overwritten with the same content of each newly inserted row.

Comment: Ah - the problem is, that a listobject/table adjusts the formula to the whole column - a added some solutions

Comment: Thank you! Just experimented with both solutions